# Lang's proof of Cauchy's Theorem

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

In proving Cauchy's theorem in his 'Algebra', Lang first

> prove[s] by induction that if $G$ has exponent $n$ then the order of $G$ divides some power of $n$. Let $b \in G, b \ne 1$, and let $H$ be the cyclic subgroup generated by $b$. Then the order of $H$ divides $n$ since $b^n=1$, **and $n$ is an exponent for $G/H$**. Hence the order of $G/H$ divides a power of $n$ by induction, and so consequently does the order of $G$, as $$(G:1)=(G:H)(H:1).$$

I don't understand why the bit in bold is true, I am happy with everything that comes before, and, if accepting the bold bit using the definition of 'exponent' described below, everything that comes after. Can anyone help by clarifying why the bold part is true?

---

I take [*an* exponent of $G$]=[*the* exponent of $G$]=[the smallest $n\in \mathbb{N_0}$ such that $g^n=1$ for all $g \in G$]. Then surely a counterexample for the statement in bold is if $G=H$, in which case the exponent of $G/H$ is evidently $0$ (as it only contains the coset $eH$)?

If Lang is here using the definition that  [an exponent of $G$]=[any $n\in \mathbb{N_0}$ such that $g^n=1$ for all $g \in G$], then the theorem is trivial, so I don't think that's what he's using.

Comment: He seems to say "an" exponent, not "the" exponent.  So, my guess would be that the latter definition is intended.

Comment: But why is $H\lhd G$ in the first place?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In that place, Lang considers only abelian groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I take [*an* exponent of $G$]=[*the* exponent of $G$]=[the smallest $n\in \mathbb{N_0}$ such that $g^n=1$ for all $g \in G$].

No, that is not right, *an exponent* of $G$ is any $n \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $g^n = e$ for all $g\in G$. Then it is clear that an exponent of $G$ is also an exponent of every factor group $G/H$.

I would not say the theorem is *trivial*, but it certainly is not deep.

Comment: In 'if $G$ has exponent $n$ then the order of $G$ divides some power of $n$', does he mean the smallest $n$?

Comment: No, any $n > 0$ such that $g^n = e$ for all $g$.

Comment: @Alyosha If $\forall g\in G\colon g^n=e$ then $\exists k\colon |G|\mid n^k$.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why this has taken me so long to grok.

Comment: Lang fixes $n$. Then he proves "for all finite abelian groups $G$ such that $(\forall g\in G)(g^n = 1)$, the order of $G$ divides a power of $n$".